# Template method in c++ static library

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I have written template method in non-template class. This project is static library.
Then I have written test console application and wanted to use this method. But there is compilation error (unresolved external). Then I asked google and have found forum (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/108544-static-libraries-template-functions.html) where 'matsp' said: "The entire template implementation needs to be in a header file when using templates.". I did like he said and it works great. Why?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612791/c-template-and-header-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's the way it is with templates in *C++*... Their definition has to be visible in every translation unit that is used.

Comment: Thanks, but you have answered me just "because". I need to know more...