# C++ template class binding to nodejs

Tags: c++, node.js, templates, binding

I want to create nodejs addon wrapping C++ class template. I converted example class from "[Wrapping C++ objects](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects)" tutorial to template. It compiles without errors but I get error upon using it.

```
node: symbol lookup error: /home/me/projects/node-template/build/Release/addon.node: undefined symbol: _ZN8MyObjectIdE4InitEN2v86HandleINS1_6ObjectEEE
```

addon.cc:

```
<...>
void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
    MyObject<double>::Init(exports);
}
<...>
```

myobject.cc:

```
<...>
template <typename T>
MyObject<T>::MyObject() {};

template <typename T>
MyObject<T>::~MyObject() {};

template <typename T>
void MyObject<T>::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
<...>
```

myobject.h:

```
<...>
template <typename T>
class MyObject : public node::ObjectWrap {
    public:
        static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);

    private:
        MyObject();
        ~MyObject();

        static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
        static v8::Handle<v8::Value> PlusOne(const v8::Arguments& args);
        T counter_;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ templates preclude separate compilation units, at least you way you've done here. Your `addon.cc` wants a `MyObject<double>`, with the assumption that it will be defined later (and resolved during dynamic linking at runtime). But `myobject.cc` doesn't know that you want a `double`-instantiated `MyObject`, so the compiler doesn't produce it when generating `myobject.o`.

To solve your dilemma, just put the contents of `myobject.cc` into `myobject.h`. That is, place the *definition* of `MyObject` in your header file; don't leave it as a separate compilation unit.

Comment: It works this way but shouldn't _definition_ be in .c/cc files and class/function prototypes in .h, should it? I mean your solution works but is it the _right_ way?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612791/c-template-and-header-files