# What is the difference between .cc and .cpp file suffix?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between `.cc` and `.cpp` file extensions?

From Google, I learned that they are both from the C++ language, but I am unsure of differences between them.

Comment: `.cpp` is 1 character longer

Comment: For added bonus, there's also, `.cp`, `.c++`, `.cxx` and `.C`.

Comment: Since the Linux kernel is written in C, are you sure those `.cc` files were even in C++?

Comment: Technically for the compiler there is no difference. However, some compilers and/or build systems will guess how to compile your files based on the extension and may or may not detect "cc" (or "cpp" but that is more rare I guess) as a c++ file.

Comment: Do you want [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: Hamming does not apply to strings of different lengths

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Conventions.

Historically, the suffix for a C++ source file was `.C`.
This caused a few problems the first time C++ was ported
to a system where case wasn't significant in the filename.

Different users adopted different solutions: `.cc`,
`.cpp`, `.cxx` and possibly others. Today, outside of the Unix
world, it's mostly `.cpp`. Unix seems to use `.cc` more often.

For headers, the situation is even more confusing: for whatever
reasons, the earliest C++ authors decided not to distinguish
between headers for C and for C++, and used `.h`.

This doesn't cause any problems if there is no C in the project, but when you
start having to deal with both, it's usually a good idea to
distinguish between the headers which can be used in C (`.h`) 
and those which cannot (`.hh` or `.hpp`).

In addition, in C++, a lot of users (including myself) prefer keeping the template
sources and the inline functions in a separate file.  Which,
while strictly speaking a header file, tends to get yet another
set of conventions (`.inl`, `.tcc` and probably a lot of
others).

In the case of headers it makes absolutely no difference to the compiler.

In the case of source files different endings will cause the compiler to assume a different
language. But this can normally be overridden, and I used `.cc`
with VC++ long before VC++ recognized it as C++.

Comment: How can I configure Visual Studio to treat a file as C++ if it is not already recognised as such?

Comment: @AviChapman, you probably can try [files.associations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)

Answer (score 24):

There is no difference. They're exactly the same.

Comment: What collation are you using? Surely this is Danish again :)

Answer (score 8):

Actually it all depends on what you and your compiler prefer. There is no difference between them at all.

Answer (score -1):

I found out `.cc` to be much used in open source projects, however, my personal preference is `.cpp`

Comment: 10 years after the question was asked? Stating a preference is not answering the question.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545080/c-code-file-extension-what-is-the-difference-between-cc-and-cpp for additional discussion of the topic.

Comment: @Clifford - The question was "what's the difference between `.cc` and `.cpp`". Since there are no more substantial differences, mentioning that `.cc` is more often used in open source code is as valid an answer as any.

Comment: @AlvinThompson. On reflection, yes, but the mention of a personal preference adds nothing.  Is it even true though?

Comment: I think it's also not true. Most projects are using cpp actually, but I like to use cc ;P haha