# Compiling .cu vs .cpp: Compiler errors even without any CUDA code

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

I compile the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

via

```sh
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
$ nvcc -O0 --std=c++14 -g -Xcompiler=-Wfatal-errors -I./include -I../boost  main.cu -o runserver
```

I get the compiler error:

```sh
boost/beast/core/impl/error.ipp(20): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::detail::error_codes"

beast/core/impl/error.ipp(55): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::detail::error_conditions"

boost/beast/core/impl/error.ipp(84): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/beast/core/impl/error.ipp(92): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/asio/impl/error.ipp(32): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::asio::error::detail::netdb_category"

boost/asio/impl/error.ipp(64): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::asio::error::detail::addrinfo_category"

boost/asio/impl/error.ipp(94): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::asio::error::detail::misc_category"

boost/beast/http/impl/error.ipp(21): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::http::detail::http_error_category"

boost/beast/http/impl/error.ipp(96): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/beast/websocket/impl/error.ipp(20): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::websocket::detail::error_codes"

boost/beast/websocket/impl/error.ipp(117): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::websocket::detail::error_conditions"

boost/beast/websocket/impl/error.ipp(144): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/beast/websocket/impl/error.ipp(152): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/beast/zlib/impl/error.ipp(49): warning: overloaded virtual function "boost::system::error_category::message" is only partially overridden in class "boost::beast::zlib::detail::error_codes"

boost/beast/zlib/impl/error.ipp(115): warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"

boost/beast/http/message.hpp(265): error: static assertion failed with "Fields type requirements not met"
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "boost::beast::http::header<false, Fields> [with Fields=boost::beast::http::fields]"
(495): here
            instantiation of class "boost::beast::http::message<isRequest, Body, Fields> [with isRequest=false, Body=boost::beast::http::string_body, Fields=boost::beast::http::fields]"
boost/beast/websocket/detail/impl_base.hpp(199): here

boost/beast/http/message.hpp(61): error: static assertion failed with "Fields type requirements not met"
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "boost::beast::http::header<true, Fields> [with Fields=boost::beast::http::fields]"
(495): here
            instantiation of class "boost::beast::http::message<isRequest, Body, Fields> [with isRequest=true, Body=boost::beast::http::empty_body, Fields=boost::beast::http::fields]"
boost/beast/websocket/detail/impl_base.hpp(257): here

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00002a42_00000000-6_main.cpp1.ii".
```

However, if I change the file suffix to `.cpp` and compile with nvcc, no problems are encountered and everything is fine.

Why? I thought nvcc just forwarded CPU code to the host compiler.

In addition, it seems nvcc has a problem with the `.ipp` files. Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 3):

> Why? I thought nvcc just forwarded CPU code to the host compiler.

That is too simplistic a statement for understanding of what is happening here.

As you've discovered, `nvcc` behavior (by default) is different depending on whether the file extension is `.cpp` or `.cu`, *even for purely host code*.

A more complete description of the nvcc preprocessing associated with `.cu` files (even for host code) is given in [the nvcc manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#cuda-compilation-trajectory).  An even more complete description can be obtained by running your `nvcc` command with `--verbose` switch; you can fully inspect the process in detail that way.

In a nutshell, host code in a `.cu` file goes through several preprocessing steps before it actually reaches the host C++ compiler.  Host code in a `.cpp` file goes through fewer steps before reaching the host C++ compiler.

In addition, boost takes on specific behavior when it detects certain macros that the nvcc compiler adds to (even) host code, when that host code is in a `.cu` file.  These macros, as detected by boost code, cause boost to "behave" differently.  [Here](https://github.com/cms-sw/cmsdist/issues/3583) is an example.

I don't think there is any problem with `.ipp` files that are used in [the conventional way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147208/difference-between-using-ipp-extension-and-cpp-extension-files).  These are merely "add-ons" to header files, following the standard include mechanism.  The fact that there are lot of `.ipp` files indicated in your error output is unrelated to this.  It's merely a consequence of where the errors are occurring and how boost partitions its header code.

If you're actually looking to address this particular issue here, the usual suggestions are:

1. Put your boost code in .cpp files
   (or)
2. Use the latest versions of boost and CUDA
   (and)
3. Report observed issues as either (or both) [boost issues](https://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html) or bugs against CUDA at developer.nvidia.com (bug filing description is [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044668/cuda-programming-and-performance/-how-to-report-a-bug/))