# Undefined reference to everything, when using libm

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, libm

I have a program using the standard maths function in C++. On my Mac, it links just fine using clang, and without even using -lm. However, on Ubuntu, also using clang, after adding -lm to my command line, I get undefined reference to EVERYTHING. I mean literally everything.

My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -pipe
LDFLAGS = -pipe
LDLIBS = -lpng -lpthread -lm
OBJS = Colour.o GraphicsLibrary/SimpleVector.o Camera.o Ray.o \
Material.o SceneObject.o Sphere.o Plane.o Polygon.o PolygonPatch.o Cone.o \
Cylinder.o Light.o Scene.o SimpleScene.o BoxedScene.o RTreeScene.o AABB.o Main.o \
AFF/parse.o AFF/texture.o AFF/animation.o AFF/quat.o AFF/kbsplpos.o \
AFF/kbsplrot.o
TARGET = straylight


######################
# ------------------ #
# Top level targets. #
# ------------------ #
######################

all: ${TARGET}

clean:
    rm -v ${OBJS} ${TARGET}

debug:
    ${MAKE} EXTRA_C_FLAGS="-g3 -pg" EXTRA_LD_FLAGS="-g3 -pg"

optimized:
    ${MAKE} EXTRA_C_FLAGS="-O3" EXTRA_LD_FLAGS="-O3"

######################
# ------------------ #
# Low level targets. #
# ------------------ #
######################

${TARGET}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} ${EXTRA_LD_FLAGS} -o ${TARGET} $^ ${LDLIBS} 

%.o: %.C %.h Makefile
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${EXTRA_C_FLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: If you want to compile C++ code, use a C++ compiler :)

Comment: I'm confused. Question is originally tagged C++ but @sehe changed it to C. The compiler being used is clang (C) instead of clang++ (C++), but CFLAGS has `-std=c++11` and makefile contains rules for compiling %.C (note capital C, usually for C++). What language are we working with here?

Comment: Make up you mind about compiler/language you are using. Right now you are completely mixing things up.

Comment: @harmic whoah. Who uses .C for c++!?!?! Mind blown

Comment: I am trying to compile C++. Using CC = clang++ solves the problem. Didn't realise there's a different executable for C++. Thanks

Comment: @sehe certainly not me, but apparently some do. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171502/c-vs-cc-vs-cpp-vs-hpp-vs-h-vs-cxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, when compiling C++, you need to use the correct compiler. `clang++` for C++.

Often the C and C++ compilers are the same basic program, but invoking them as eg. clang or clang++ invokes them with the correct options for the target language.

Most likely the errors you saw were the result of the program not being linked against the correct runtime libraries.