# How do I add cpp file to an arduino project?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to add a cpp file to arduino project that has the following setup...

```
project 
--folder
  --foo.h
  --foo.cpp
--project.ino
```

I have a `#include "folder/foo.h` at the top of `project.ino`. However while the header provides the prototype of the function, the function definition is in the cpp file. When I try to compile the code using the Arduino IDE, it fails with error
`Undefined reference to 'bar()'`
and `bar()` is located in `foo.cpp`

I looked at [this](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=219439.0) but I do not have a setting for `sketch/import library` (however I do have `sketch/include library`, however I did not see anything close to using a custom folder location)

I looked at [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) too. But same as above, that setting does not exist in my ide. (Which I downloaded recently)

Code

```
//project.ino
#include "folder/foo.h"
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    bar();
}
```

```
//folder/foo.h
#include "Arduino.h"
void bar();
```

```
//folder/foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

void bar() {
    Serial.println("bar");
}
```

Error

```
/tmp/ccNTRFfU.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `loop':
/home/temporary/project/project.ino:9: undefined reference  to `bar()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

What I would expect to happened is a way to link the cpp folder without having to put all the files in the same root folder of the project.

--Edit 1: 
added code

--Edit 2: 
added `#include "Arduino.h"`

--Edit 3:
added `Serial.begin(9600);`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here. Make sure that `bar()` has exactly the same signature as declared in `foo.h`.

Comment: Open a tab in your project for each file. You can create a new file or import an existing file into your project.

Comment: If you add a complete and verifiable example, as requested above, I'll upvote this question.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, added.

Comment: I just upvoted your question now that it is complete and contains all pieces necessary to duplicate it exactly. I don't know why you got downvoted again. The first one made sense when your question had no code. The last one makes no sense. This is now a good, solid question. Good job.

Comment: I have to say that the Arduino "IDE" really isn't suitable for larger projects. If you add one or two additional files it may be fine, but anything beyond should really use something else. There's a reason that the Arduino IDE calls its programs "Sketches" because if you got beyond prototyping with it you should use something else. I can recommend Visual Studio Code with the Arduino extension or Visual Studio Community Edition with Visual Micro depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to properly include C/C++ headers and source files in your Arduino Project

### Quick summary

(Added June 2023)

Arduino is C++, with some C source code and object files mixed in, but they have added some preprocessing steps to their build system which make it behave slightly differently from normal C++.

So, to include your own custom header files, you must:

1. Ensure all source files have the `.cpp` extension, not `.c`. Your files are already fine in this regard. Last I checked years ago, Arduino also prefers header files to end in `.h`, not `.hh` or `.hpp`.
2. Ensure you **put your custom header and source files in the same directory as your project `.ino` file.** So you need to fix this.

   Do this:

   ```
   project
       foo.h
       foo.cpp
       project.ino
   ```

   *Not* this:

   ```
   project
       folder       <-- custom subfolders are not allowed in Arduino!
           foo.h
           foo.cpp
       project.ino
   ```

   You'll then include your custom library like this:

   ```cpp
   // Inside project.ino
   #include "foo.h"
   ```

   I haven't tested it yet, but Arduino may also recognize and be okay with a directory named `src` only.

   Possibly okay:

   ```
   project
       src
           foo.h
           foo.cpp
       project.ino
   ```

   If you use a `src` folder, one of the following includes should work, but I haven't tested it to see which:

   ```cpp
   // Inside project.ino
   // (I haven't tested this)

   #include "src/foo.h"
   // or maybe 
   #include "foo.h"
   ```

That's about it. I'd have to try the latest Arduino IDE and command-line build system to see if anything has evolved or improved over the last few years regarding includes.

You can stop here if the above works for you. Or, read below for more info. and details and learning.

### Original answer details

(Written 2019)

*This answer has been tested and compiled to ensure it works.* (Completed in Linux Ubuntu with the Arduino 1.8.7 IDE).

You have 2 problems.

**1st:** Arduino's unusual build process ([described here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process)) doesn't allow including from sub-folders in your project directory where your `.ino` file for this project is located.

*[UPDATE: THIS ONE MAY HAVE BEEN MY MISTAKE ONLY, NOT YOURS, when I was duplicating your code on my PC: I accidentally used `foo.c` instead of `foo.cpp`]*
**2nd:** C++ can only be used inside C++ source files, so you must change `foo.c` to `foo.cpp`, since `Serial.println()` is a C++ call to a C++ class's (`Serial`'s) `println()` method.

**To fix 1**, simply change your folder structure to have everything in a single folder:

```
project
├── foo.cpp
├── foo.hh
└── project.ino
```

I present an alternate fix for #1 below too.

**To fix 2**, (this is mandatory!) make `foo.c` --> `foo.cpp` and (optionally, but recommended, to show it is a C++ header file) `foo.h` --> `foo.hh`. Update your includes in the .ino and .cpp file now too to `#include "foo.hh"`. Update 7 June 2023: just use `.h`. Arduino may not like `.hh`, but I haven't tested this in the latest Arduino IDE. Your call.

That's it! Now close the Arduino IDE, then reopen it and reopen your project, and you'll see the following new tabs show up:

[image]

It now compiles just fine!

### Learning: how did I figure this out?

First, turn on verbose compilation in the Arduino IDE: File --> Preferences --> check the box for "Show verbose output during 'compilation'".

Now, when you compile, all errors will show up in the bottom of the IDE window, as well as the *exact* compilation or linking commands which throw the error.

Once I fixed the folder structure, but your files were still C instead of C++ files, I saw this error:

```bash
Compiling sketch...
/home/gabriel/Downloads/Install_Files/Arduino/arduino-1.8.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_NANO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/home/gabriel/Downloads/Install_Files/Arduino/arduino-1.8.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/gabriel/Downloads/Install_Files/Arduino/arduino-1.8.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/eightanaloginputs /tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c -o /tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c.o
/tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c: In function 'bar':
foo.c:9:5: error: 'Serial' undeclared (first use in this function)
     Serial.println("bar");
     ^
/tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c:9:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
exit status 1
'Serial' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Notice the file it failed to compile was `/tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c`, and that the `avr-gcc` C compiler (rather than the `avr-g++` C++ compiler) was in use at the time.

I then opened the `/tmp/arduino_build_233569/sketch/foo.c` file to examine it and look for anything unusual about it.

Next, I used Eclipse to start tracking down includes, to see where `Serial` gets pulled in (it should have been obvious to me already what the problem was, but I didn't see it yet). I found the following:

**Arduino.h** is found in "Arduino/Source/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h". It includes `"HardwareSerial.h"`. This header `extern`s the `Serial` object:

```cpp
#if defined(UBRRH) || defined(UBRR0H)
  extern HardwareSerial Serial;
  #define HAVE_HWSERIAL0
#endif
```

HOWEVER, looking back at `Arduino.h` you'll see that `HardwareSerial.h` is ONLY included if you are compiling with C++:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus   // <========= This means that the following headers are ONLY included if you are compiling with C++! BOOM! That's when it hit me! You're compiling a C file with the C compiler to access a C++ object. That's not ok. Use the C++ compiler!
#include "WCharacter.h"
#include "WString.h"
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "USBAPI.h"
#if defined(HAVE_HWSERIAL0) && defined(HAVE_CDCSERIAL)
#error "Targets with both UART0 and CDC serial not supported"
#endif
```

`#ifdef __cplusplus` means that the headers above are ONLY included if you are compiling with C++! That's when it hit me! You're compiling a C file with the C compiler to access a C++ object. That's not ok. You must use the C++ compiler instead. Do this simply by changing `foo.c` to `foo.cpp`. Done.

### Alternate fix for your problem #1 (the folder structure):

Find your "Sketchbook location" from Arduino IDE: File --> Preferences. Mine, for example, is `/home/gabriel/dev/Arduino/Sketches`.

Now, go there and create a "libraries" folder. For me that would now be `/home/gabriel/dev/Arduino/Sketches/libraries`. Everything inside this folder is now considered an Arduino "library", and can be included. Move `foo.h` [do NOT use `foo.hh` in this case] and `foo.cpp` there, like this:

```
/home/gabriel/dev/Arduino/Sketches/libraries/foo
├── foo.cpp
└── foo.h     <==== NOT foo.hh in this case!
```

Now close and reopen the Arduino IDE, then go to Sketch --> Include Library --> foo, and it will automatically add the following line for you:

```cpp
#include <foo.h>
```

The reason you can't use `foo.hh` in this case is simply because Arduino is looking for `.h` files only when you add your library include using the menus in this way. **That's a bug as far as I'm concerned, and should probably be reported to the Arduino developers.** Feel free to take that on.

### Addendum:

16 Apr. 2019:
A [google search for "arduino add include path"](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%20add%20include%20path&oq=arduino%20add%20include%20&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2.2410j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) led me to this: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=445230.0, where user @pert says:

> In recent versions of the Arduino IDE(including 1.6.10) if you want to include libraries from the sketch folder you need to put them in a src subfolder. For example:
>
> ```
> Blink  
> |_Blink.ino  
> |_src  
>    |_BlinkLib  
>        |_BlinkLib.h
> ```

He then says you can include like this:

> ```cpp
> #include "src/BlinkLib/BlinkLib.h"
> ```

I haven't tried this, but that'd be super useful if it works. Give it a shot and let me know if it works. Be sure to tell us which OS and Arduino IDE version you are using.

### See Also:

1. Additional discussion on Github here: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/5186.
2. The official Arduino Library specification here: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/library-specification/.

Comment: why .hh instead of .h when including files locally?
Also, what about `#include "project/foo.cpp"`? That seemed to have compiled *and ran* . which makes me think, the extension doesn't get checked.

Comment: .hh instead of .h is simply a personal preference to mark C++ headers as C++ headers. So long as you are consistent, it really doesn't matter what you use. At work we use .h for C headers, & .hh for C++ headers, & .c for C source files & .cc for C++ source files. Other commonly used extensions include .hpp or .h++ for C++ header files, & .cpp or .c++ for C++ source files. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171502/c-vs-cc-vs-cpp-vs-hpp-vs-h-vs-cxx. As for `#include "project/foo.cpp"` working, I can't say, but I suspect your thought about the full path not getting checked is correct.

Comment: I just added an Addendum to the bottom of my answer. Try putting the sub-files in a `src` folder inside your project folder, and report back if that works as well.

Comment: The answer could just be a short answer about where to put the cpp file. The 2nd problem was eventually a problem made in the answer and shouldn't be occupying most of the answer because it is out of topic and unrelated with the question.
Should be deleted, or moved to the bottom of the answer with *Unrelated Topic* title

Comment: @izzulmakin, I see your downvote, and your point. Answer updated. Hopefully it's good enough to merit a change of vote.

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Sketch specification"](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.29/sketch-specification/#src-subfolder):

> ```
> In Arduino IDE 1.6.5-r5 and older, no recursive compilation was done.
> In Arduino IDE 1.6.6 - 1.6.9, recursive compilation was done of all subfolders of the sketch folder.
> In Arduino IDE 1.6.10 and newer, recursive compilation is limited to the src subfolder of the sketch folder.
> ```

So, putting your source code files into 'src' subfolder should solve the problem. Tested in "Arduino IDE" v2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Open a tab in your project for each file.
You can create a new file or import an existing file into your project.
This way you can use multiple `*.ino`, `*.c`, `*.cpp` and `*.h` files. I didn't find a way to import a local directory or to configure your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your `folder` inside `libraries` folder that is a subdirectory of your sketchbook directory.
2. Open Arduino IDE (if it is already open, quit it and reopen).
3. Go to `Sketch->Include Library`. You will find `folder` under `Contributed Libraries` section.
4. Choose `folder` and you are good to go.