# Cannot create a working makefile. Understand nothing about it

Tags: makefile

I assume most of you will think I did not try to search on the internet by myself but I really did. I understand nothing on makefile and I tried to create one for c++. 
I have only two files: Set.hpp and main.cpp.

Here is my wrong makefile.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS= --std=c++0x --pedantic -g -Wall -W
LDFLAGS= 
EXEC=main

all: $(EXEC)

main: Set.o main.o
        $(CC) -o main Set.o main.o $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) -o main.o -c main.cpp $(CFLAGS)

Set.o: Set.hpp
    $(CC) -o Set.o -c Set.hpp $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

The error I get is simply `Make: * no targets. Stop.`. I really need help for this please :/ Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This makefile looks fine, but your error message seems bizarre.  It looks to me like the make program can't find your makefile.  Is that really the EXACT error message you see?  What platform are you running on?  What did you name the makefile?  Is it in the current directory?  How did you invoke make?

Comment: You didn't use spaces instead of tabs by any chance, did you?  The wacky indentation seems to suggest this but it could be a copy/paste error, too, of course... You need literal tabs (ASCII 9) on all commands.

Answer (score 0):

`.hpp` files are header files. They are NOT to be complied. They are to be included in the source file. You can find more about the `.hpp` files and some related info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152555/2173917).

Now, to start with a "working" version of your makefile, let's consider the following points. I assume you have two source files

```
 1. main.cpp
 2. Set.cpp
```

and one header file

```
 1. Set.hpp
```

in the same directory. Please consider the sample files provided below.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Set.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        call_func();
        cout <<"And this is from main.cpp"<<endl<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

#### Set.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Set.hpp"
using namespace std;

int call_func()
{
        cout<<"This is from set.cpp"<<endl<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

#### Set.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int call_func();
```

#### Makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS= --std=c++0x --pedantic -g -Wall -W
LDFLAGS=
EXEC=main

all: $(EXEC)

main: Set.o main.o
        $(CC) -o main Set.o main.o $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) -o main.o -c main.cpp $(CFLAGS)

Set.o: Set.cpp                                  # notice the change from .hpp to .cpp
        $(CC) -o Set.o -c Set.cpp $(CFLAGS)     # notice the change

clean:
        rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
        rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

After that, the output is like

```
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]# make
g++ -o Set.o -c Set.cpp --std=c++0x --pedantic -g -Wall -W
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp --std=c++0x --pedantic -g -Wall -W
g++ -o main Set.o main.o 
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]# make 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]# make clean
rm -rf *.o
[sourav@infba01383 so_overflow]#
```

Hope this helps!!!