# Including hpp files in an R package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I'm writing an R package making use of Rcpp to call functions written in C++ into the R code. Some of these functions and templates are written in files with a .hpp extension following the convention used by boost (and also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152555/h-or-hpp-for-your-class-definitions)).

This does not result in an error when building (`R CMD build .`) and checking (`R CMD check --as-cran package.tar.gz`) the package, but it returns the next warning:

```
Subdirectory ‘src’ contains:
  file.hpp example.hpp
These are unlikely file names for src files
```

Ok, this is not a big issue, but my concern is, **why** the warning? is naming *hpp files considered a bad practice in the R community? Are there objective  or community reasons why I should use *cpp/*h files instead of *hpp for the templates?

Comment: It is a warning issued by _R_ so you are asking the wrong people here in  the `rcpp` tag: go and ask R Core, and/or (re-)read [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) which details all there is to know about R extension packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I originally left this information as a comment, but realized it actually answers your question I think, so here goes:

As Dirk Eddelbuettel points out in the comments, when you have a question about an R Core Team policy on R extension packages, your best bet is to look through their excellent [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual. This manual tells you almost anything you could ever need to know.

In your case specifically, you needed to look at [Section 1.1.5](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories), which explains that "[the R Core Team] recommend[s] using .h for headers" because (as they explain in footnote 18) "Using .hpp is not guaranteed to be portable."

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the advice!